# Getting my application to go to domain.com instead of www.domain.com

Tags: redirect, heroku, dns

I have a Heroku hosted website (bought on Godaddy) that I am trying to get to redirect to thisdomain.com instead of www.thisdomain.com.

My DNS records on GoDaddy look like this:

```
A        @     50.63.202.24
CNAME   www    thisdomain.herokuapp.com
NS       @     ns19.domaincontrol.com
NS       @     ns20.domaincontrol.com
```

I also have permanent (301) forwarding to www.thisdomain.com.  I know this is the opposite of what I want, but right now, thisdomain.com won't work without it.

How do I do this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to host your application on a root domain. Heroku by itself doesn't support this functionality but does suggests some ways of doing it, and it is quite possible.

Here is heroku documentation for configuring application to run on root domain - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains

To know about why Heroku does not support root domain you read the following article - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains